# How to solve Maths Problem without algebra way. Primary School Question

Tags: problem-solving

Caroline bought a school bag, a pair of
shoes and a jacket for her son.
She paid a total of $\$170$.
The pair of shoes cost $\$23$ more than the school and $\$16$ less than the jacket
How much did Caroline pay for the jacket?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  And to explain why you want to avoid Algebra.  After all, Algebra was invented to solve problems like this one.

Comment: @lulu I can shed some light on that. It's one of those idiotic aspects of the "modern" Singapore primary school math curriculum, where they want students to use "models" rather than symbols to solve problems. They claim not to penalise students who learn algebra on their own and use it, but they often do penalise these poor kids.

Comment: @Deepak Thank you for that explanation. I'd be interested to see what a "model" would look like here.  Have you got a link to an example handy?

Comment: @Deepak Oh, I see you posted an answer here.  I'll read that.  Thanks agan.

Comment: Are the schoolchildren required to collapse their compass when making a model?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_equivalence_theorem

Comment: @lulu For example here (a pdf download link, don't be alarmed): https://www.hmhco.com/~/media/sites/home/education/global/pdf/white-papers/mathematics/elementary/math-in-focus/mif_model_drawing_lr.pdf For what it's worth, I'm not sold on the whole nonsensical models thing, so I may not have given a very "model" answer (no pun intended).

Comment: @Deepak  Thanks.  I think I've got the notion. For very simple problems, like the one in this post, I can even see some value.  But I can't imagine doing it for more elaborate problems.

Comment: @lulu Ah, there's the rub. They actually expect you to use it for problems with varying proportions etc. It's the most pointless mind-bending I've ever had to do! Let me dig around and find a ridiculous example for you.

Comment: @lulu For example, (an actual question) Allan had 60 stamps more than Becky. They each gave away some stamps. Becky gave away 2/5 of the number Allan had at first. Allan gave away 2/3 of the number Becky had at first. Both had an equal number of stamps left. How many stamps did Allan have at first?

Comment: @lulu Another gem. 

 

A,B,C and D each have some money.

 
A has 1/3 of the total B, C and D have.

 

B has 1/4 of the total A, C and D have

 

C has 1/5 of the total A, B and D have. 

 
D has $92.

 

How much do they have in total?

Comment: @lulu The last one for now, to avoid spamming the comments: There were 500 beads in 4 jars P Q R and S. If the number of beads in P was halved, the number of beads in Q was increased by 18, the number of beads in R was tripled and the number of beads in S was decreased by 24, they would all have the same number of beads. What was the difference in the number of beads between P and Q at first?

Comment: @lulu There are even more twisted problems out there the misguided Singapore educators expect kids to solve with "models" and not "letters". But I'll stop with those.

Comment: @Deepak  There's a frustrating phenomenon out there in which (some) math educators  find what they regard as an intuitive approach to some problem, or class of problems, and then elevate it to Dogma.  In some instances the intuitive method is even useful and worth describing.  But I don't understand the impulse to then force the method into an unconvincing universality.

Comment: @lulu Very well said.

Comment: Are you going to accept any of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Since the (idiotic, in my view) Singapore system wants you to avoid algebra (by which they seem to mean letters representing variables), draw a block to represent a school bag, the cheapest item. The shoes are a block plus $23$ dollars. The jacket is a block plus $23+16 = 39$ dollars.

The sum of all the three items is $170$. If you clip away the excess of $39$ and $23$ from the two more expensive items, you get three blocks. Three blocks will add up to $170 - 39 - 23 = 108$. One block will be $36$. That's the price of the school bag. So the price of the jacket is $39$ more, or $75$ dollars. Done.

Comment: A more charitable interpretation would probably be that what the the school system or teachers in question want to discourage is _mindless symbol churning_. While algebra is a wonderful invention and can help keep track of computations that are much too complex to keep in one's head, students _also_ need to develop familiarity with the concrete calculation that the algebra _stands for_. Otherwise they might end up considering The Rules of symbolic manipulation to be just magic which works not _because_ anything, but simply because authority says so. (...)

Comment: (...) From a mathematics education perspective that's just as bad as not learning symbolic algebra at all. Of course, this can be implemented too heavy-handed; bad math teachers an make everything impossible. But if you're teaching two views that are both necessary, it's not _a priori_ "idiotic" to set exercises that are supposed to train one view even though the other would give the same _result_.

Comment: The relation of the sign to the thing signified is being destroyed,  the game of exchanges between signs is being multiplied of  itself and for itself. And the increasing complication demands  that there should be signs for signs. . . .

Comment: As collective thought cannot exist as thought, it passes into  things (signs, machines . . .). Hence the paradox: it is the thing  which thinks and the man who is reduced to the state of a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are about to pay for the three items. The cashier says it's 170. Then you say: I changed my mind, instead of the school bag I'll take another pair of shoes. Then the cashier says: it's 23 more for a total of 193. Then you change your mind again: instead of the jacket I'll take another pair of shoes. The cashier says: Then it's 16 less, the total is now 177 for three pairs of shoes. Now you know that each pair of shoes is 177/3=59, so the school bag is 59-23=36 and the jacket is 59+16=75.